No Entity Framework data source shown in VS2019 when use DevExpress v21.2
After I add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model, the tables are shown and everything is fine. I use DevExpress and try to add Entity Framework, but the issue is that no data source is shown. I just need to know the problem and how to added correctly.
See this screenshot:
enter image description here
I use Visual Studio 2019, SQL Server 2014, and DevExpress v21.2

Did you try using your favourite search engine to look for the message: "No available data sources are found in the solution. Please create a new data source." Do the DevExpress tickets shed no light on the issue?
